# How to set up LongClick in ListActivity to create AlertDialogue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, long-click

I have stumbled trying to set up AlertDialogue following onLongClick in my ListActivity. As shown below, I have set up the onListItemClick to open an AlertDialogue without problem and it works fine, but I can't find the correct method for envoking the LongClick on top of this:

```
public class InspectionActivity extends ListActivity {
private Button newInspection;
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;

private RMDbAdapter rmDbHelper;
private AlertDialog clickOptionsDialog;
private String inspectionDialogueText;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);
    setUpViews();
    rmDbHelper = new RMDbAdapter(this);
    rmDbHelper.open();

    // Get a Cursor for the list items
    Cursor listCursor = rmDbHelper.fetchAllInspections();
    startManagingCursor(listCursor);           

    // set the custom list adapter     
    setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));

}

private void setUpViews() {
    newInspection = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_inspection);
    newInspection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createInspection();
        }
    }); 

}

// In your ListActivity class, create a new inner class that extends ResourceCursorAdapter. 
//This inner class is the custom CursorAdapter we will use to manage how data is bound to list   item:

private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter { 

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        super(context, R.layout.inspection_row, cursor);

    } 

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inspection_row_item_main_title);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(                            
                cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)));

        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inspection_row_item_description);        

        String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "Company unknown");
        String inspectionDate = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_DATE)), "date unknown");
        description.setText("(" + companyName + ", " + inspectionDate + ")");       
    }      
}

private void createInspection() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, InspectionEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}


protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int pos, final long id){

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchInspection(id);

    String inspectionRef = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)), "Reference unknown"); 
    String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "company unknown"); 

    inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")"; 

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    clickOptionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InspectionActivity.this)
    .setTitle(inspectionDialogueText)
    .setMessage(R.string.general_text_select_option)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.general_button_open, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), inspectionDialogueText + " (Area activity to be created)", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            clickOptionsDialog.cancel();
            }
        })
    .setNeutralButton(R.string.general_button_export, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), inspectionDialogueText + " (Export activity to be created)", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            clickOptionsDialog.cancel();
            }
        })

    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            clickOptionsDialog.cancel();
            }
        })
    .create();
    clickOptionsDialog.show();
```

Thanks for your help!!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the onListItemLongClick event with OnItemLongClickListener to handle long click on listview items.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but where do I place teh OnItemLongClickListener please?  Is there an example you know of - please remember I want to envoke a AlertDialogue not a ContextMenu..

Comment: I guess this is correct (but I can't test right now) protected void onListItemLongClick(ListView l, View v, final int pos, final long id){} as a method of your Activity class. Inside this method you can put any code you want (event an AlertDialog)